# Properly using asset catalog for iPad Pro

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, asset-catalog

In my app I have image edge to edge and I'm trying to set different image for iPad and iPad Pro 12.9.
The resolution is really different between Pro and non-Pro version, so I have to use different image size.
It's possible using asset catalog or I have to use an `if-else` in code?

Comment: Would like to know that as well. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use size classes for that.

Import the two images into an Asset Catalog and set the larger image for Any Size Class (Width Class/Height Class) and then limit the smaller image for rest (Compact/Regular).

[image: See Width Class and height Class]